# CKeditor 4 - Jquery for content only brings back PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

I am having a problem getting updated content from ckEditor. The Textarea is prepopulated with the post information and so is ready to be updated. However when I pull the information through Jquery all it does is pull the PHP variable that I used to populate the editor not the updated text.

textarea Code

```
<textarea id="editBody<?php echo $Post_id ;?>" name="body<?php echo $Post_id ;?>" ><?php echo $body; ?></textarea>
```

Jquery Code

```
var body = $("#editBody"+id).val();
```

I have tried several solutions but non work correctly like the below

```
var body = $(CKEDITOR.instances.CKeditBody+id.getData).val();
```

This just brings back NaN in the alert

```
var body = CKEDITOR.instances.CKeditBody"+id.getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all apologies for this post. I Was looking at an older version of CKeditor manuals than I needed.

The solution was

```
var body = CKEDITOR.instances['editBody'+id].getData();
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.